# Is there a gpg-agent for cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, gnupg

I would like to use gpg-agent from cygwin, but installing gpg on cygwin doesn't provide it, and google doesn't have much recent information about this. Is it possible to use gpg-agent under cygwin (with something like keychain), or can I use a "native" windows agent with cygwin's gpg?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, no (or not yet, as of March 2016). As the following thread from the Cygwin package maintainer for GnuPG suggests, gpg-agent is only available in GnuPG 2 and newer, but Cygwin is packaged with GnuPG 1.4.

- https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2015-09/msg00067.html

*On 04/09/2015 12:31, Andrew Schulman wrote:*

> So, why isn't there a
>   gpg-agent for Cygwin?  Any hope of having one some day?

*From: Adam Dinwoodie*

> I suspect simply because nobody has packaged one, and somebody has to
>   do the work to make it available.  I doubt anyone would object to you
>   submitting an Intent To Package per https://cygwin.com/setup.html.

*On Thu, Sep 03, 2015 at 03:20:45PM -0400, Andrew Schulman wrote:*

> If that's the only reason, I could certainly look at packaging it.  I
>   guess I'd like to hear from Marco first though, the gnupg maintainer,
>   to tell us if there isn't some other reason.

*From: Marco Atzeri*

> for what I know gpg-agent belongs to GnuPG > 2.0 while we have only
>   the classic gnupg-1.4.19
>
> If I remember right GnuPG > 2.0 requires memory protection features
>   that do not exist on cygwin. But I could be wrong.
>
> Regards
>   Marco

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE (2018-10-20)**

> The information below is now obsolete, since as of today the current Cygwin *gnupg2* package version is at **`2.2.10-1`** and the one coming with the most recent *gpg4win* (3.1.3) is at `2.2.10`.

---

No, there is currently no native Cygwin package for **GnuPG 2+**. Please file a complaint on their email list. The only way is to follow [my installation instructions](https://superuser.com/a/1207635/116221) and soft link the new agents. Be careful as there are several files with similar names, as you don't want to break the native/original gpg used by the package manager and other apps.

```bsh
$ ls -1 /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/GnuPG/bin/gpg*

gpg.exe'*
gpg-agent.exe'*
gpgconf.exe'*
gpg-connect-agent.exe'*
gpgme-w32spawn.exe'*
gpg-preset-passphrase.exe'*
gpgsm.exe'*
gpgtar.exe'*
gpgv.exe'*
gpg-wks-client.exe'*

$ ls -1 /usr/bin/gpg*

gpg.exe*
gpgsplit.exe*
gpgv.exe*
gpg-zip*
```

The bare minimum to link are:

```
$ ln -s /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/GnuPG/bin/gpg.exe /usr/bin/gpg2
$ ln -s /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/GnuPG/bin/gpg-agent.exe /usr/bin/gpg-agent
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to switch to [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download-home-edition.html) !

MobaXterm has a keychain–like utility that saves ssh sessions much like mRemote-ng, but is a native Unix terminal for Windows (like Cygwin).

Comment: Good idea, but I thought MobaXterm's MobAgent feature was intended as an SSH agent for forwarding SSH keys. Can you provide any details about how to set MobaXterm up in a way that it can act as a substitute for GnuPG, or where to find examples or documentation?

Answer (score 0):

If Cygwin cannot provide a GnuPG > 2.0 due to memory management limitations, you could try looking at the new [Microsoft Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl/about) to [run Bash on Ubuntu on Windows](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/).

From within the Bash shell (running on Ubuntu on Windows 10 via WSL) you have access to the Canonical package repositories and can quickly install things like GnuPG:

```
apt-get install gnupg
```

Comment: GnuPG 2+ runs fine for me in Cygwin. But other packages I use use GnuPG 1, hence the desire for *gpg-agent* for that version.

Comment: @nwaltham is specifically asking for Cygwin, which is not using apt-get.

Comment: I read the question, but I am pointing out there's new alternatives to Cygwin now on Windows that provide GNU and *nix toolchains