# how to install gpg on cygwin? currently it's missing

Tags: cygwin, gnupg

I have cygwin installed on Win 7 but can't see gpg in `/usr/bin/`.. is this normal? How can i get it? I am trying to verify a linux ISO and need this to check the signature file.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Luckily, gpg is included in Cygwin's software repository. Just run the cygwin installer([`setup-x86_64.exe`](https://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe) or [`setup-x86.exe`](https://cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe)) again, and when the package select menu comes up, search for "gnupg". Check the "gnupg" option that appears under utils, finish the update, and you're done. It should install gpg and any dependencies.

If, for some reason, this does NOT work, you can compile it yourself. I can give detailed instructions upon request, but for now- [this page](https://www.maketecheasier.com/compile-linux-programs-under-windows/) explains how to compile (most) linux programs under Cygwin, and [this page](https://www.gnupg.org/download/git.html) provides instructions on downloading the source code.

Comment: followup: i am trying to verify the authenticity of gpg4win (from their site). i have a trusted gpg install already. when i import their certificate i seem to get a different fingerprint then what's listed on the web-site.. is that possible?

Comment: If the signature is the proper one for that file, it should match. If not, you're either doing something wrong, something isn't acting like it's supposed to, or someone messed with the file. To troubleshoot- try downloading gpg4win again or using the SHA1 checksum to verify instead. Also, since this question is now about GPG itself rather than Cygwin, I recommend asking it separately(you have a very narrow chance of finding an expert in both Cygwin and gpg)

Comment: Worked fine to compile, just remember to compile and install the GPG libs. The `configure` of GPG script will tell you which ones to get though, if you miss something.

Comment: There is no gpg in Cywin 1.7.33.

Answer (score 14):

**UPDATE (2018-10-20)**

> The information below is now obsolete, since as of today the current Cygwin *gnupg2* package version is at **`2.2.10-1`** and the one coming with the most recent *gpg4win* (3.1.3) is at `2.2.10`.

---

Unfortunately the *Cygwin* provided [packages for GnuPG](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=gnupg) is way outdated and still using the deprecated **gnupg1.4**. This is indeed sad as everything else seem to work great. So you might think to download the Windows native [Gpg4win](https://www.gpg4win.org/download.html), but that is a mistake. Also that package is outdated (as of 2017-05-10) with the latest release of **2.3.3** (2016-08-18), only using **gnupg 2.0.30**. So what to do?

Instead, go to the GnuPG [download page](https://gnupg.org/download/index.html) and select the download labelled as *"Simple installer for the current GnuPG"*. That will download the latest *.exe from their [FTP site](https://gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/binary/). Install it. GnuPG Bugs are tracked [here](https://dev.gnupg.org/).

However, the old original Cygwin **gpg** binary is located in `/usr/bin/gpg.exe` and that path is taking precedence over the new Windows one. So to see the new version you have to give the full path.

```bash
$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.21
...
Home: ~/.gnupg
...

$ /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/GnuPG/bin/gpg.exe --version

gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.20
libgcrypt 1.7.6
...

Home: C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Roaming/gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

The easy solution to reach the new binary is by soft-linking it.

```bash
$ ln -s /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/GnuPG/bin/gpg.exe /usr/bin/gpg2
$ ln -s /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/GnuPG/bin/gpg-agent.exe /usr/bin/gpg-agent
# And others depending on your need

$ gpg2 --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.20
libgcrypt 1.7.6
...
```

All good! Finally, notice that your key-chains will be located in the Cygwin `$HOME` for the old gpg, whereas in the `/cygdrive/c/Users/xxxx/AppData/Roaming/gnupg/` for the new one.

Of course, you can always go the long way of compiling and installing the latest from [sources](https://gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/gnupg/).

Comment: I just want to note that gnupg2 is an available package on cygwin now. It's not quite the latest (currently 2.1.23 compared to 2.2.1 available directly from GnuPG), but a great improvement over the prior state of affairs.

Comment: This version seems to be incompatible with the original gpg in Linux. It crashes with "gpg: packet(13) too large".

Answer (score 4):

The real answer for me, in 2020, is that it's called

**gpg2**

in cygwin now, not gpg.  How was I supposed to know that? The cygwin package is gnupg2, which is not found if one searches for gpg in the cygwin installer.  As this thread is the top hit searching for "gpg cygwin" maybe I'll save someone some time.

Answer (score 2):

I did following to use GPG2 with Git on Cygwin (including gpg-agent for caching GPG passwords):

- Installed the gnupg2 Cygwin package (version 2.2.27-1).
- Configured git to use gnupg2:
  `git config --global gpg.program $(which gpg2)`