# How to get gpg2 installed on cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, gnupg, rvm

Trying to install gpg2 on win10. Followed bottom answer on this thread; [how to install gpg on cygwin? currently it's missing](https://superuser.com/questions/1115841/how-to-install-gpg-on-cygwin-currently-its-missing/1207635#1207635?newreg=854add64a6fa493c8cd9e2f87b742434)

but got a problem when trying to soft linking them;

I have "the right" version when checking the new download;

```
$ /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/GnuPG/bin/gpg.exe --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.21
libgcrypt 1.7.6
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later 
<https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: C:/Users/xxxxxxxxx/AppData/Roaming/gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
    CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

And the old version is;

```
$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.20
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: ~/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, RSA-E, RSA-S, ELG-E, DSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
    CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: MD5, SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

Having liked both;

```
$ ln -s /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/GnuPG/bin/gpg.exe /usr/bin/gpg2
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/gpg2': File exists

$ ln -s /c/Program\ Files\ \(x64\)/GnuPG/bin/gpg-agent.exe /usr/bin/gpg-agent
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/gpg-agent': File exists
```

I don't get why I get this message;

```
$ gpg2
C:/msys64/usr/bin/gpg2: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open 
shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am doing this because of;

```
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

ERROR: Could not find GNU compatible version of 'tar' command, make sure it's available first before continuing installation.
```

If there is any other way around this to get RVM installed, I'll be happy to know

Comment: Why are you not installing it through Cygwin? `gnupg2-2.1.21-1` - gnupg2: GNU tool for secure communication and data storage is [available from Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fgnupg2%2Fgnupg2-2.1.21-1&grep=pgp)

Comment: I did, but they only have gpg 1.4 in their setup; https://imagebin.ca/v/3SfnlmLOcfp9

Comment: Reaceaching how to install individual packages now, not so fammiliar with it on Cygwin.

Comment: I found apt-cyg, but then I have to install  **wget**, **tar**, **gawk** and **bzip2**, and then its just easier to fix the issue over, isen't it?

Comment: No they don't. See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### I'm trying to install gpg2 on win10

There is no need to install gpg2 using the complicated instructions in the link you have provided.

The [gpg2](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=gpg2&arch=x86_64) package is available through the normal Cygwin installer. If you install it using this it will be correctly configured.

- Run the install program
- Continue until you get to the "Select Packages" screen
- Set the "View" to "Full"
- Set "Search" to "gnupg2"
- Click the first "Skip" (it will change to the version number 2.1.21-1)
- Click "Next" to install

  [image]

Answer (score 2):

As reported by David, GNU Privacy Guard version 2 is available
on `Cygwin`
https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2017-06/msg00080.html

as last version of 1
https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin-announce/2016-08/msg00109.html

The two versions coexist in parallel.